# Open Cart Endless Loop

Tags: .htaccess, opencart, redirect-loop

I'm working on an open cart site and I was editing the .htaccess file to allow for SEO friendly URLs.

The system is in a subdirectory if that helps.

Some of the work was done prior to me taking on the job by another developer who isnt providing any help at the moment. (I've took out the actual url as I can  only currently post a limited amount of links per post)

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ http://www.furnishingsdirect.co.uk/new
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.furnishingsdirect\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.furnishingsdirect.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.furnishingsdirect.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The second .htaccess file contains:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteBase /new/
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Whenever I try to access the website through the url

http://www.furnishingsdirect.co.uk

or

http://www.furnishingsdirect.co.uk/new/

It states that "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

I'm positive that this code was fine earlier till I altered the web forwarding through 123 reg. I forwarded the furnishing direct domain so that it always directed users to the directory with the shop system in it. I think that is what has cause the issue, 123 reg says it will take some time for the site to adjust but Im unsure. Can anyone help shed some light on this situation? any help would be appreciated.

The DNS for this domain is pointing to web hosting, it was originally pointing to the 123 reg holding/forwarding service.

Comment: I'm not a redirect expert but I think this rule `RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ http://www.furnishingsdirect.co.uk/new` will always redirect to `http://www.furnishingsdirect.co.uk/new`, even if the URL is `http://www.furnishingsdirect.co.uk/new` already since Apache will apply `.htaccess` from `http://www.furnishingsdirect.co.uk` first and then from `http://www.furnishingsdirect.co.uk/new/` as well... Isn't it? I think You should redirect to `/new/` only if the URL does not contain that part, shouldn't You?

Answer (score 0):

your problem probably is in the config.php file, if this constant was defined to your root, and your .htaccess redirect to your /new, you get into a loop. look at this on your config.php file:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.furnishingsdirect.co.uk/');
```

and change to '/new'.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all if you have 2 .htaccess files, please use the second one as it is closer to the default one the first has many changes to it. Or better yet if you find extensive trouble download a new .htaccess from the Opencart site (for the appropriate version ofc.)
2. Secondly check your config.php that

   `define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://domain/');` 
   and

   `define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://domain/');`

are set correctly.

Except from defining the base there should be no other need for your cart to be functional, if you want to add custom .htaccess code please add at the end of the .htaccess files (that is the way i use some domain redirects for example)